# How to stick TabWidget in top of the screen while scrolling the layout in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a tabwidget in my code. How to stick that in top of the screen in layout?

```
<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:tabStripEnabled="false">
</TabWidget>
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: what type of parent layout are you using?

Comment: see my code below am given

Comment: sry am not able post my code here, am using linear layout

Comment: Use android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

Comment: can you explain briefly ?? please

Answer (score 0):

Try this using relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:tabStripEnabled="false">
</TabWidget>
```